# How to run a command on all .cs files in directory and store file path as a variable to be used as command on windows

Tags: batch-file, svn, command-line, cygwin

I'm trying to run the following command on each file of a directory.
`svn blame FILEPATH | gawk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c`
It works well however it only works on individual files. For whatever reason, it won't run on the directory as a whole. I was hoping to create some form of batch script that would iterate through the directory and would grab the file path and store it as a variable to be used in the command. However, I've never written a batch script nor do I know the first thing about them. I tried this loop but couldn't get it to work
`set codedirectory=%C:\Repo\Pineapple% for %codedirectory% %%i in (*.cs) do` 
but I'm not necessarily sure what to do next. Unfortunately, this all has to be run on windows. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: from `cmd` `@for %i in (*.cs) do @echo svn blame %i | gawk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c` and in batch-file `@for %%i in (*.cs) do @echo svn blame %%i | gawk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: Unfortunately. I failed to specify that I will need to be able to scan multiple folders deep. While this works, I just need to figure out how to scan deeper. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: Made some slight alterations and now it's working. Thanks so much for the help! For anyone who might want it: `@for /R %i in (*.cs) do svn blame %i | gawk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c`

Answer (score 0):

use `for` and `find`, similar to example on

https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

```
for i in $(find . -name "*.cs"); do
  svn blame $i | gawk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c 
done
```